# WPF Transition image to title menu in game

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi everyone 
i creating a game now, i want to create an image transition from company promotion to movie of the game and after that display the title menu.
i need your help everyone...
please help me to create a C# code of WPF which transition :
1. display and image as long as 3 second
2. the image fade and display the title menu, i have a method to call title menu callTitleMenu().
*didn't need transition to movie, from image direct to title menu
thanks yeah

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a Storyboard that animates the opacity of an element (the image) to 0 starting at 3 seconds and taking as long as you wish for.
2. Subscribe to the Completed event of the Storyboard and use this handler to add anything you want to the UI.

Your question isn't quite clear but this should get you started.